# What are the limits on dynamic/double dispatch in Kotlin?

Tags: dynamic, dispatch, kotlin

I'm just starting to explore Kotlin, and I'm curious about how far it moves beyond Java's core dynamic binding/dispatch semantics.

Let's say I write code that looks something like this:

```kotlin
class Animal {
    fun add(x:Animal) = Animal()
}

object Horse : Animal
object Donkey : Animal
object Mule : Animal

fun Horse.add(x: Horse) = Horse()
fun Horse.add(x: Donkey) = Mule()

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val h: Animal = Horse
    val d: Animal = Donkey
    val child = h + d
}
```

Based on the above code above, what can I expect to happen? Do I get a failure at runtime because `Horse` doesn't implement `add(Animal)`? Can it accurately differentiate them in calls of the above nature, where the compile-time type of the values being compared was `Animal` (at least, as written) but their runtime types were more specific?  Does it change anything if we used `var` instead of `val`?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Modified core code--I see the problem the first responder highlighted, I wasn't thinking straight.  Clearly I haven't actually compiled this, I'm still kind of exploring at a conceptual level.

Also, I will give it a shot in the actual compiler, but I'm concerned that there will be situations in which it works and others in which it doesn't based on some criteria that I don't fully understand.  I wasn't able to find reference docs on how dynamic dispatch is implemented in Kotlin (not sure about it for Java either, for that matter; I wrote something a few months ago that I thought would work based on JVM docs, but it didn't, and I never had a chance to explore exactly why).

Anyhow, thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's a version of your code that actually compiles:

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    val h:Animal = Horse
    val d:Animal = Donkey
    val child = h + d
    println(child)
}

open class Animal {
    fun plus(x:Animal) = Animal()
}

object Horse : Animal()
object Donkey : Animal()
object Mule : Animal()

fun Horse.plus(x:Horse) = Horse
fun Horse.plus(x:Donkey) = Mule
```

The result is "Animal@1906bcf8".

As far as I understand, extension methods, i.e. `Horse.plus(x:Horse)` and `Horse.plus(x:Donkey)`, are statically dispatched. That's because they are basicly compiled to the same byte code as the following Java code:

```
static Horse plus(Horse $receiver, Horse x) {
    return Horse.INSTANCE;
}
```

By the way, this is a big difference to default methods in Java 8 which are dynamically dispatched based on the runtime type and can be overriden.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Makes a lot of sense.  I'll take this a bit further with my own exploration.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not compilable at all, because Animal doesnt have any "+" operators.

If they would allow to use Horse "+" methods on an Animal,
then you'd get runtime errors, which kotlin/java/etc. tries to prevent.

Kotlin wont work with the runtime-type to resolve methods and stuff,
because there are possibilities to produce runtime errors.

What if another thread changes Animal to a Mule in the meantime, the exact line/time when the other thread changes the Animal is not deterministic, so this could lead up to runtime errors.

Val or var doesnt change anything in this situtation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I see the problem.  I modified the question code to hopefully be closer to sensible.